# How to use four spaces for indent in vim editing?

Tags: vim

The default editing is indenting with tab, I tried to change ~/.vimrc to indent with 4 spaces, but I failed. I find it is useful to use the setting Text Editor Indentation here in Jupyter config:

[image: Jupyter config]

Answer (score 0):

hmm, I think 2 tools is not related. jupyter-lab is web-based, and `.vimrc` is config for your vim in local computer. Therefore, you can not config in `.vimrc` to make it works in `jupyter-lab`

Comment: exactly, but I tried to use command in vim windows such as : set tabstop=4, but it didn't work either.

Comment: ah ok, now I understand your question. You want config indent in vim like what jupyter did. Have you tried `set shiftwidth=4`?

Comment: thx, my question actually is when I use vim in terminal, I can use set tabstop=4 command line, however when I use vim editing mode on web-based jupyter-lab page I cannot use command line anymore. But it's okay now since we have a workaround.